# Angular js wait for service call return

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to Angular.js.
I have simple application which has dynamic form. I use [this](https://github.com/danhunsaker/angular-dynamic-forms) plugin in my app.

I have API which returns the json response with controls to be loaded on page. In `success` callback I assign scope variable response but it doesn't seems to be working. Here is my code
 http://plnkr.co/edit/YTKloQpeiTTSEx4zVIAI?p=preview

Comment: Can you tell us more about the failure? Is there a failure or is your form just not populated? It would also be nice to know if the ajax call has actually be made or not.

Comment: angular after 1.0.8 (don't know exact version) has very useful ngIf directive. So you could do `<dynamic-form ng-if="loaded" template="stdFormTemplate" ng-model="stdFormData"></dynamic-form>` – and it would render just after data is loaded. On your place I would update angular _or_ google an old version of ngIf directive that had place in angular-ui plugins pack a long time ago (I remember because i used it then).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ve spend few minutes to fix this directive to watch attribute changes

```
 $scope.$watch(attrs.template, function(newValue, oldValue) {
   if (newValue === oldValue) { 
     return;
   }

   //  Grab the template. either from the template attribute, or from the URL in templateUrl
   (attrs.template ? $q.when($parse(attrs.template)($scope)) :
     $http.get(attrs.templateUrl, {
       cache: $templateCache
     }).then(function(result) {
       return result.data;
     })
    )
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/BWXlsvJ73yeTumh83wqh?p=preview

Comment: Don't like approach with editing third-party libraries. If author will update library, it'll become more complicated to update on our side.